# Is there a way to define a to_json handler in GDScript?

Tags: json, godot, gdscript

I'm new to GDScript and am looking at how best to save data to a text file. `to_json` works well for basic types but I just get a reference id for any custom classes. I'd ideally like to pass a dictionary of data including some custom class elements to `to_json` and let it convert it all at once.

Like other languages provide a `toString` method for printing an object, is there anything that would let me specify how a class instance should be converted to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you would just add something like the following to your class:

```
func to_json():
    var data = {} #must create it as a dictionary or array
    data["health"] = 5
    #code to create json
    var json
    json = data.to_json() #dictionaries automatically have this function
    return json
```

I think it really is that simple :)

Please note: I have not tested this code.